# Start up Application Chromium

Tags: startup, chromium

How to add chromium to run in start up? I used the command which you can see in image. But it's not working. I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I have updated both OS and browser up to date.

[image]

Comment: Use `sh -c 'sleep 30; chromium-browser'` as a command and see how it does.

Comment: Try adding the full path to Chrome in the command field, not the filename only. To find out where the executable is, type `whereis chrome` in the shell.
Second possible way: create a .desktop file in **~/.config/autostart/** to start Chrome after you logged into the DE.

Comment: Also the command might be just `chromium` and not `chromium-browser` depending on where you installed it from ... so check this by running them in the terminal to see which one works.

Comment: @Raffa the last one which you said worked. Many thanks.

Comment: @noisefloor thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @karel Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Using the appropriate snap command to launch the default Chromium snap would be more reliable in case the loop device is not fully initiated yet. Instead of `chromium-browser` use `snap run chromium` in the *Command:* field of the *Edit Startup Program* window to launch Chromium.

Comment: Assuming it was installed from snap ... Then, yes, `snap run chromium` would be more reliable in case the loop device is not fully initiated yet.